# método para restar dos fechas en C# y hallar años y meses

Tags: c#, datetime

Tengo estas dos fechas declaradas como variables:

```
DateTime birthDay =this.metodoX(objeto.birthdate.Value); 

DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
```

Ambos me dan una fecha de tipo DateTime. El primero me lo coge de la BBDD. El segundo es la fecha actual. 
Quiero calcular cuantos años y meses hay entre la fecha de la BBDD y la de hoy. Ejemplo:

Fecha BBDD: 19/03/2000

Fecha de hoy: 20/05/2019

Hay 19 años y 2 meses (el día no lo quiero).

¿Hay algún método que haga esto directamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacer esta comparación:

```
static string ObtenerEdad(DateTime birthday)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var yearsOld = now - birthday;
    int years = (int)(yearsOld.TotalDays / 365.25);
    int months = (int)(((yearsOld.TotalDays / 365.25) - years) * 12);

    return $"Tienes: {years} años {(months > 0 ? $"y {months} meses" : "")}";
}
```

Lo que hace es lo siguiente:

- Resta a la fecha actual `now` tu fecha de nacimiento `birthday`
- Obtiene la cantidad de años dividiendo el total de días entre `365.25` (cantidad aproximada de días en el año)
- Obtiene la cantidad de años en `double` menos la cantidad de años en `int` (para obtener el residuo) y a este se le aplica una regla de tres para transformarlo en la cantidad porcentual de meses

Al final regresa una cadena con la información obtenida.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Perfecto!!! muchas gracias @Gabriel Aragón.

Answer (score 0):

La comparación la haces con una operación matemática que te regresa un tipo de dato TimeSpan:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2019, 5, 20, 12, 33, 3);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2019, 5, 21, 22, 33, 3);

TimeSpan difference = end - start;

Console.WriteLine("Difference in days: " + difference.Days); // 1 (solo compara días)
Console.WriteLine("Difference in days: " + difference.TotalDays); // 1.41666666666667 (compara la fecha completa)
Console.WriteLine("Difference in hours: " + difference.Hours); // 10 (solo compara     horas)
Console.WriteLine("Difference in hours: " + difference.TotalHours); // 34 (compara la fecha completa; 1 días + 10 horas)
```

Para saber todas las opciones que TimeSpan tiene para el cálculo, te puedes referir a la documentación: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.timespan?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#propiedades

Comment: esto solo me deja operar con días y horas. Necesito años y meses...

Comment: Utiliza tu intellisense, te dará muchas opciones, con esas puedes encontrar la que te sirva...

Comment: Tus respuesta servirán unas veces y otras no. Te vendría muy bien asumirlo para seguir participando de manera constructiva en un foro como este. Gracias igualmente.

Comment: He agregado la referencia a todas las opciones que el tipo de dato TimeSpan ofrece. Espero sea suficiente.

Comment: XD Lo solucioné hace ya dos días gracias a la respuesta de @Gabriel Aragón. Gracias!!